# how to parse a flat file (in python) with FIX message format?

Tags: python, fix-protocol

Anyone knows what is the best way to parse a FIX-Protocol version 4.4 format flat file in python?

I came across **`quickfix44`** module but can't find information on how to use that module against a flat file as opposed to live streaming fix messages.

Any other utility already available in python that could accomplish this reading from a FIX-Protocol file which also automatically handles the repeating groups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could call out to this online tool https://fixparser.chronicle.software which provides the parsed fix message back as JSON.